# Binding not updating (INotifyPropertyChanged) in ControlTemplate for Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, controltemplate

I cannot seem to get a WPF ControlTemplate binding to update on a regular getter property using INotifyPropertyChanged. See the example below.

I have the following C# WPF Class:

```
public class ExampleControl : Control, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Number", typeof(int),
        typeof(ExampleControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));
           
    public int Number
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NumberProperty); }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(NumberProperty, value); 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
        }
    }
           
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (Number * 2).ToString();
        }
    }
            
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And am using this Style containing a ControlTemplate:

```
<Style TargetType="local:ExampleControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ExampleControl">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSourceAncestorType=local:ExampleControl}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It does work the first time the control is loaded (so the binding is working). But when the "Number" Property of ExampleControl gets updated, the TextBlock in the ControlTemplate does not update correspondingly. I do want to base the Text property on the value of the Number DependencyProperty. What do I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: Does `OnPropertyChanged` get called when you change `Number`? Can you set a breakpoint to confirm? And can you clarify how `Number` is being changed?

Comment: In the first place, you don't need the Text property in this case. Bind the Number property directly.

Comment: As a general note, you should not implement INotifyPropertyChanged but leave all binding stuff to DependencyProperty in a view element which inherits DependencyObject.

Comment: @rshepp OnPropertyChanged is not getting called. That's an important sign. I was updating the Number property using a Binding in the DataTemplate of a ListBox. Confusingly a regular textbox (right next to this control) does get updated using the same Binding.

I tried changing the Number property manually in code and this does fix the issue. I will see how to fix it using Binding.

Comment: @emoacht: The above code is overly simplified, in the real scenario I'm doing a little bit more than just converting the Number to a String. I'll update the example above to reflect this.

I will see if I can create a read-only dependency property. Thank you.

Comment: @Jordy Be aware that dependency properties provide their own change notifications. You do not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: The property setter is not called when a dependency property is set by data binding. In order to react on changes of a dependency property, register a PropertyChangedCallback with property metadata.

Comment: @Clemens This has solved it, thank you!